# How to boot Macbook Pro when in closed clamshell mode without the windows getting resized

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a mid 2012 MacBook Pro that I use an external 1440p monitor/keyboard/mouse with.

[Another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14800/powering-on-while-the-lid-is-closed-in-clamshell-mode) shows it's not possible to boot it without opening the lid. When I do this, all of my windows resize/move to fit the 900p internal display, messing up my work environment every time I bring my computer from sleep.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Posting this as a comment because my laptop is older than yours but if it's correct I'll make it an answer. With my 2007 MBP I can get it out of sleep by clicking a mouse button or key on my external keyboard with the lid closed. No problem. On a cold boot, I press the power button and then close the lid as fast as I can, and then it boots up on the external monitor with no ill effects. Do either of these work for you?

Comment: Yes, this does work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my 2007 MBP I can get it out of sleep by clicking a mouse button or key on my external keyboard with the lid closed. No problem.

On a cold boot, I press the power button and then close the lid as fast as I can, and then it boots up on the external monitor with no ill effects.

Should work that way for any MBP!